# Compatibility Reporting Services 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like know if build reports in reporting services 2017, i can deploy in another server which have reporting services 2012?

This is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can, 
If you're using SSDT 2017(Visual Studio) go to  Project > [Project Name] Properties > Target Server Version > change to the desired version. 
[image]